# using multithreading to do OCR with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, ocr

I need an advice on multithreading implementation in WinForms C# application. We have an image - with **text** and **numbers** and there are **separate methods** to OCR different types of data. For example:

```
decimal[] numbers = getNumbers(bitmap, dictionary1);
string[] text = getText(bitmap, dictionary2);
int[] integers = getInts(bitmap, dictionary3);
// add 5 more data types (list, int[], etc..)
```

**As the result, whole proccess takes approximately 1 second.**

I was thinking about running OCR on different threads, simultaneously. For that reason I tried to use Task Factory:

```
decimal[] numbers;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{numbers = getNumbers(bitmap, dictionary1);});
string[] text;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{text = getText(bitmap, dictionary2);});
textBox1.Text = "" + text[0]; // nothing
```

but I was not getting any results..

so **is it possible to implemet multithreading in my case?** Which approach do I have to use?

- task factory
- background worker
- threads
- or something else?

If possible, can you give me a little advice on how to use your method, because TaskFactory failed when I tried to use it (as in example).

**Edit:**

seems like

```
textBox1.Text = "" + text[0];
```

was executed faster than

```
string[] text;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{text = getText(bitmap, dictionary2);});
```

that's why TextBox field was empty.. so I moved "textBox1.Text = "" + text[0];" at the very end of the code, and finally got the result..

**Edit 2:**

ok, tasks do not make any difference.. I'm getting the same speed test result without them.

Comment: Does Your actual code wait for the tasks to complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're starting tasks correctly, but you're never waiting for them to finish. What you want to do is something similar to;

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
decimal[] numbers;
tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {numbers = getNumbers(bitmap, dictionary1);});
string[] text;
tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {text = getText(bitmap, dictionary2);});

Task.WaitAll(tasks);  // Wait for all parallel tasks to finish 
                      // before using their output.

textBox1.Text = "" + text[0];
```

More example code can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610.aspx).

Alternately, you can return the value from the task instead of assigning it to a variable and use [Task.Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) which when you access it will wait for the task to finish and return the result of the Task.

Comment: tasks do not make any difference.. I'm getting the same speed test result without them.

Comment: @Alex Hard to explain without seeing the new code, but are you starting all tasks first and accessing the result once they're all running? If you're waiting for the result for each task separately before starting the next, you'd get the same effect.

Comment: I'm starting them exactly as in your example: run1, run2, run 3 ->>> WaitAll. Then I'm putting gathered info into textBoxes. And that's not all. On the first run there aren't any errors, but when I run my code the second time, I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (unless put troublesome line into a separate task[])

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Finally, I know what was causing this error that I was talking about.. Performance increased by 200+ ms which is not such a bad result.. all is better that 1 second ;)